# Excel VBA - How do copy and transpose paste another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I try to copy data from Workbooks with Sheets("daily shift report") to another Workbooks Sheets ("Sheet1") by transpose according to the code below.

```
Sub copyDatafrommultipleworkbookintomaster()
Dim FolderPath As String, Filepath As String, Filename As String, Erow As Range
FolderPath = "C:\Users\YIT\Documents\test\April57\"
Filepath = FolderPath & "*.xls*"
Filename = Dir(Filepath)

Do While Filename <> ""
Workbooks.Open (FolderPath & Filename)
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("daily shift report").Range("B71:G77").Copy
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.Close


Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
Filename = Dir

Loop
End Sub
```

But found Run time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error.I guess error in line 14.
**Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True**
Could you please suggest a solution to this problem?.

Comment: So, there is an open workbook having a sheet named "Sheet1") where you need to paste from the opened workbooks? `Everytime in Range("A1")` overwriting the existing contents? Is really that you want? Would you like to copy at the last empty row? Or on the next column?

Comment: Do you have a single such a workbook in the mentioned folder?

Comment: But, is there only a single such .xls file in the mentioned folder? If not, it sounds strange to paste everything in the same cell...

Comment: @FaneDuru 1.Yes,I want to paste in workbooks having a sheet named "Sheet1".       
 2.Now yes overwrite everytime 3.Not yet 4. the next column 5.Many file in FolderPath

Comment: It is a contradiction between what you marked as 2 and 4. If everything is overwrite, how to paste in the next column? I do not understand what 3 is referring at ...

Comment: Try my answer code, please. If it does not return where you need, you sill have something to evaluate and say what does happens differently against your wish.

Comment: Couldn't you find some time o test the above code, please?

Comment: @FaneDuru . I test already.Code that you write perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try the next code, please. It will Paste, from each existing .xls workbook, in the next empty column of "Sheet1":

```
Sub copyDatafrommultipleworkbookintomaster()
 Dim FolderPath As String, Filepath As String, Filename As String
 Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, Col As Long
 
 Col = 1
 Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
 FolderPath = "C:\Users\YIT\Documents\test\April57\"
 Filename = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xls*")

 Do While Filename <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & Filename)
    wb.Sheets("daily shift report").Range("B71:G77").Copy
    ws.cells(1, Col).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
    Col = Col + 7 'increment the next col where to paste
    wb.Close False
    
    Filename = Dir
 Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. This is useful for me.

Comment: @Ninlawat Phuangchoke: Glad I could help! Should I understand that it is only useful, but it did not answer your question?

Comment: That code is solution. can i contact you directly in email ?

Comment: @Ninlawat Phuangchoke: When a piece of code answers your question, we here tick the  code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works... Then, what is to  be clarified by mail? I like helping people, but here on stackoverflow. I let people send their workbook only in cases may solution works on my computer and not on their environment and I like to understand why... :)

Answer (score 0):

Please see if either of following two set of codes is useful to you.

1. Mention your Source File Path & File name directly as string

```
Sub GetData()

Dim customerFilename As String
Dim customerWorkbook As Workbook
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet, sourceSheet As Worksheet

    'targetSheet is Activeworkbook wherein you would want to fetch the data
    Set targetSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    'Mention Source-file path & file name between double quotes below
    customerFilename = "C:\Users\YIT\Documents\test\April57\Your_File_Name_Here.xls"
    
    Set customerWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(customerFilename)
    
    Set sourceSheet = customerWorkbook.Worksheets("daily shift report")
    
    sourceSheet.Range("B71:G77").Copy
    'select in which cell you want to paste data
    targetSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    customerWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

2. In this code you will be prompted to select Source File (.xls or .xlsx or .csv), no need to manually write Source Filepath & Filename.

```
Sub GetData2()

Dim filter As String, caption As String
Dim customerFilename As String
Dim customerWorkbook As Workbook
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet, sourceSheet As Worksheet

    'targetSheet is Activeworkbook wherein you would want to fetch the data
    Set targetSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    'Prompt to get the customerWorkbook i.e. Source Workbook
    filter = "Excel and CSV Files (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.csv),*.xls;*.xlsx;*.csv"
    caption = "Please Select an input file "
    customerFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)
    
    Set customerWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(customerFilename)
    Set sourceSheet = customerWorkbook.Worksheets("daily shift report")
    
    sourceSheet.Range("B71:G77").Copy
    'select in which cell you want to paste data
    targetSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True 
    customerWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Hope these codes are useful to you. Regards.

Comment: @NinlawatPhuangchoke Please accept as answer if you feel provided code is useful to you. Thank you.